# Can i use foreach loop to send response for an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery, yii

Sorry if its a silly question.I am making an ajax call to the php script to get some data and here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
var finallydata=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=typeof finallydata;

 }

  }
var url='http://localhost/path/to/my/script';
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php script in YII

```
if($timevalue != 0)
        {
            $model=new Products;
            $receivedata=$model->retrieveresult($timevalue);
            foreach($receivedata as $finaldata)
            {
                  header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('table'=>'products',array('productId'=>$finaldata->productId,'productName'=>$finaldata->productName,'Creation_date'=>$finaldata->Creation_date)));
            }
        }
```

Now since i have to send multiple records of data but one by one then can i use foreach loop for it. I am a newbie and do not know whether it will work or not. can anyone help please?

Comment: Short answer: no. You can deliver ONE response per call, so ONE header and ONE string

Comment: So sir, if i have to send multiple records of data , i will need multiple requests???

Comment: Exactly. Or concatenate them into one result

Comment: ok sir, thanks for clearing this out. Advice is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send multiple Content-Type headers. Sending multiple lines of JSON doesn't make sense anyway. Why not `echo json_encode($receivedata);` right away? Or, inside your `foreach` loop: `$results[] = array( /* Your stuff here */ );` and after the loop `echo json_encode($results);`, which would send an *array of arrays*.

Your Javascript code is putting in the `div` the *type of the response* (you're using `typeof`), which would read out as 'object' - not what you expected, but your JSON response is an object for JS, so makes sense. You should think what you want to do with the arrays in JS once you get the data there.